# Spark with Hadoop on Linux in Intellij Idea unable to find class path

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a small code snippet in Intellij

I m reading the file using the line

```
val logFile = "/home/dir1/workspace/dir2/part-00000"
```

But it is giving me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.loadFromSystemProperties(SparkConf.scala:73)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:55)
at PageRankGraphx$.main(PageRankGraphx.scala:9)
at PageRankGraphx.main(PageRankGraphx.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I dont expect this error since I have already taken the

```
spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
```

setup.

Following are the contents of my spark/conf/spark-env.sh

```
# If 'hadoop' binary is on your PATH
export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)

# With explicit path to 'hadoop' binary
# export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(/path/to/hadoop/bin/hadoop classpath)

# Passing a Hadoop configuration directory
# export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop --config /path/to/configs classpath)
```

TIA

Comment: On IntelliJ, go "File" -> "Modules" -> "+" -> "JARS or Directory", add the jars. Hopefully this can solve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: _"I am trying to run a small code snippet in Intellij"_ Is this part of a project? What's the build tool? Why don't you define a library dependency so IDEA has it available when you run the code?

Comment: I am not using any build tool as of now.

Comment: @Jacel: I tried using SBT but wasnt much successful with it. Can you please point me to some link that tells me how to define library dependencies. That said, is there I can fix this without SBT ?

Comment: Ideally, you would use Maven, Gradle, or SBT. You are missing the Hadoop classpath jars in your classpath Intellij does not read `spark-env`, only `spark-submit` does

Comment: Thanks cricket_007. I have started using sbt and most of my errors have gone away. I am facing new  errors and am trying to debug them now.